# How do I get the html list to render in my header?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my html:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button
            class="navbar-toggle"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target=".navbar-collapse"
          >
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Home</a>
        </div>
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Category</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Category</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Category</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Category</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          ...
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

And the render:
[image]

It should be showing the 4 "Category" elements across the top but it's not.  Any ideas on why these elements are acting like they're hidden?  I was originally trying to render as an ejs template but even reverting back to `html` doesn't seem to be working.  This template can be found here: https://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/storystrap

Comment: I believe the `collapse` class in the `nav` element is hidden it. Have you tried to move your "category" tags next to your "home" link? I mean, inside `<div class="navbar-header">`

Comment: More info: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/#supported-content

Comment: if I just remove the ```collapse``` class, then the links show, but they're vertical now...

Comment: ok got it to be horizontal again by removing the ```navbar-nav``` class and then the spacing correct by adding ```nav-item``` to the ```li``` and ```nav-link``` to the ```a```, the only issue i have currently is that this row is underneath the row for "Home" now

Comment: Can you please update the question with the new code and a new screenshot? I will take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the "Category" elements are not showing across the top has to do with your version of bootstrap.

If you use install and use Bootstrap version 3.3.7, then the "Category" elements will be shown across the top, and they won't be collapsed.